# libcurl DNS lookup

Tags: c, dns, libcurl

I am using libcurl with pthreads to do some POST requests to a single website. This website may change over time. I want this program to be as fast as possible. So one thing came to my mind was to first find the website IP address, then pass this IP instead of the website URLs to threads.

At first, do you think this is a good thing to do? As it removes the DNS lookup time in each connection (thread).

And how can I do this in libcurl? Is there any function to just find the IP of a hostname? Or is there any other simple way to do this in C language?

Comment: You're looking for `getaddrinfo()`. But it sounds like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem that the DNS query system in your OS is supposed to solve.

The performance improvement you want by not doing an additional lookup is countered by the fact that the IP can change over time.  Any queries should be cached presumably respecting some record timeout rules set by the DNS entry.  Windows and OS X cache requests automatically out of the box as far as I can tell.  On my debian box I found I had to enable the systemd-resolved service for this feature.  Not knowing your needs, is probably the most sane general solution to what you're describing.

Doing this with getaddrinfo() and caching it yourself for some period of time within the bounds of your program (even to disk) is a valid solution if you want absolute control and don't want to hardcode it somewhere (in the app or something like the hosts file).